# Sys.exit(1) after caught exception in python or raise exception again

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I wonder how to best handle exceptions in python and to inform the user about it.

I came across the following ideas:

Option 1:

```
try:
    do something
except MyError as e:
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit(1)

next code
```

Option 2:

```
try:
    do something
except MyError as e:
    logger.error(e)
    raise e

next code
```

Option: 3

```
try:
    do something
except MyError as e:
    logger.error(e)
else:
    next code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three differ in behavior, and you choose which one makes sense in your scenario.

In option #1, you're saying "This is a fatal error, but I want to die 'cleanly' instead of dumping a full traceback to screen."

With option #2, you're saying "I want to log the error, but I'm not handling it; maybe someone higher up the stack will?"; if nobody catches it, it behaves similarly to option #1, aside from (by default) dumping a traceback to the terminal.

With option #3, you're saying "This isn't a fatal error, and we can keep going even if it happens, but certain actions should only be done when the error doesn't occur."

I will note your option #2 is (usually) wrong; you want plain `raise` to reraise the exception without resetting the traceback or causing exception chaining (which `raise e` would do), making it behave as if you never caught the exception (aside from the logging output).